# Can I send static response via aws api gate way?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am creating an AWS ApiGateway & it invoking a lambda function asynchronously. Once apigateway sent the message lambda it'll send a 200 response with empty response. I need to send some static information with in the response message.

```
{
    "code":"SUCCESS",
    "description":"Successfully sent to lambda"
}
```

I tried to set up a model. But there I'm unable to set static values. Please help on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure [AWS API Gateway Integration Response Data Mapping](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html) return the response message from your Lambda function. If you use Lambda proxy, you can directly send the entire response including headers.

Note: If its only a static response, you don't need Lambda, you can use a Mock Endpoint with static message response.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I read the above mentioned document & able to fix that. Since I'm invoking the lambda asynchronously, apigateway didn't wait for the lambda response. once invoked the lambda, it will send an empty response. I need to override that for static success reply. I configured a model in method response & template in integration response. in integration template i added static values. now its working

Comment: For future users, you have to setup an "asynchronous" Lambda invocation if you don't want to wait for the lambda to run, and you want to respond immediately: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integration-async.html